# How can I add and get all my database table values (numbers) and displaying the total amount? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, database, oledb, datareader

I am since recently struggling with a new problem. I've got a database table that contains multiple fields (columns) with a few rows containing (money - decimal) values that are related to the fieldnames.

**For example:**

- table = money
- Field names: Rent A, Rent B, Rent C
- Values: $10, $20, $30.

What I want to do is getting these values from the database, add them together and displaying the total amount in a label.

Up till now I used the OleDbDataReader for all my outputting/storing value needs. Though I have absolutely no clue how I can add the read values since the reader usually expects an pre defined field name to read.

In my project however, a user can add a custom new field name (so a pre defined field name in the reader isn't possible because you don't know which custom field names will be added by the user in the DB. These custom added fields names and their values need to be added in the total amount as well though..

Does anyone have a clue how I can fix this?

I've tried multiple things like storing it in an array, defining decimal variables and using something like `x = x + (decimal)reader[0]` but this all didn't work so I think I am way off.

The code (and query) I am using for the reading part is as follows:

```
try
            {     
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;

                string query = "select * from money where [Month]='January'";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {      
                    //Something I tried
                    //x[0] = (decimal)reader[0];
                    //x[1] = (decimal)reader[1];
                    //And so on...

                    //Another thing I tried
                    //list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
                //list.ToArray();
                //int sum = list.Sum();
                // y = x[0] + x[1] + ...;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
```

Comment: why don't you calculate it on the fly once you have read the value of the field from the database? hold the total value in a variable. so not only do you read the value from the DB you also increment a total value held locally in the method.

Comment: It's a really really bad idea to use **SQL Server keywords** like `Money` (a datatype) or `Month` (a built-in function) for your table and column names.....

Comment: I know, but those are actually not the words I used, I just translated them for you guys;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to declare a variable, then add up all the columns. If you don't know the number of columns in the reader, you can get that using [`reader.FieldCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx).

You do not need to know the column name to get data from the reader. You can access it by column index as you started to do, e.g. `reader[0]`, or using the helper methods such as `GetDecimal(0)`.

```
try
{     
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    string query = "select * from money where [Month]='January'";
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // start the total at 0
    int total = 0.0m;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // loop through all the fields in the reader
        for(int f = 0; f < reader.FieldCount; f++) {
            // read as a decimal and add to the total
            total += reader.GetDecimal(f);
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
```

Comment: Ok, It doesn't work just quite yet. I changed the int total to a decimal (was getting errors using int for total). When I execute the code using an button I am getting the following error; ErrorSystem.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.ValueDecimal().... On line 67 which is: total += reader.GetDecimal(f); *Just a note: The database values are valuta (money).

Comment: Update* got it fixed, noticed in my database I had a text field name which obviously results in the wrong cast (the month obviously). Really stupid of me;)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps -

```
decimal total = 0M;
while (dr.Read())
{
      for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
      {
            total+= (decimal) (dr[i] != DBNull.Value ? dr[i] : 0.0);
      }
}
```

this will add all the column's value for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Datareader has property called field count which can give number of columns.. so you can use it something like below

```
double num=0.0m;
 for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
        num += rdr[i];
```